# How to get PointCloud and Pose using ARCore on android?

Tags: java, android, arcore

I am trying to get the point cloud and pose data of a scene using the ARCore. However, I am not able to figure out the starting point i.e. what will the starter code to get that data? 
I would very much appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to acquire the session's ArFrame as follows

```
Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
```

Then call the acquirePointCloud method

```
PointCloud pointCloud = frame.acquirePointCloud()
```

After this, the points in the cloud can be dumped into a FloatBuffer for processing:

```
FloatBuffer points = pointCloud.getPoints()
```

This dumps the points into the float buffer in sets of 4 points (x,y,z,c). Iterate through the FloatBuffer to acquire point locations and confidence. This should be called in an onUpdate method attached to your Scene

(As an aside, look through the ARCore sample apps code, it shows exactly how and where to implement these functions)